# Data consolidation using Oracle query

Tags: oracle, consolidation

I have to consolidate the data using oracle query in a way such that

1. if detail records matches with different headers, then display the latest header and detail set among all.
2. if detail records varies between different headers then display that corresponding header and detail.

consolidation should happen only when the details records match.

example:
Header table

```
col1
HDR1 
HDR2
HDR3
```

Detail table

```
col1 col2 
HDR1 DET1 
HDR1 DET2 
HDR2 DET1 
HDR2 DET2 
HDR3 DET1 
HDR3 DET2 
HDR3 DET3 
HDR4 DET4 
HDR4 DET5
```

expecting the result as

```
HDR2 DET1 -----> detail record matches between HDR1 and HDR2, hence 
HDR2 HDR2 
DET2 HDR3 
DET1 HDR3 
DET2 HDR3 
DET3 HDR4 
DET4 HDR4 
DET5 HDR5
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U687.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.